# Exclude a local TypeScript library from application bundle

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

How can I exclude a local TypeScript library from the bundle that is created for my application? In my use case, I want to provide the bundle for my TypeScript library  and the bundle for my application as separate JavaScript files.

## My Library

**index.ts**

```
export class Greeter {
    public greet(): void {
        console.log("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "3.1.1",
        "ts-loader": "5.2.1",
        "webpack": "4.20.2",
        "webpack-cli": "3.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack"
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".ts"] },
    output: { filename: 'bundle.js', library: '@mylib', libraryTarget: 'umd' },
    module: { rules: [ { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' } ] }
};
```

## My Application

**index.ts**

```
import {Greeter} from "@mylib/index";

new Greeter().greet();
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "3.1.1",
        "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        "ts-loader": "5.2.1",
        "webpack": "4.20.2",
        "webpack-cli": "3.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack"
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": { "@mylib/*": ["../mylib/src/*"] },
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    resolve: { extensions: [".ts", "js"], plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({})] },
    output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: { rules: [ { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' } ] }
};
```

In my example, the library code is included in the bundle of the application. I would like that the library will be **not included** so that I can provide it as a separate bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding
>   dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle
>   relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment.
>   This feature is typically most useful to library developers, however
>   there are a variety of applications for it.

You want to ad `@mylib` as an external library in the webpack config.

```
externals : {
  '@mylib': 'mylib',
},
```

In addition, Typescript also needs the typings for the library.
So you need to define them in a typings file.
This is a working example

typings.d.ts

```
declare module '@mylib' {
    export class Greeter {
        greet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately typescript cannot find 'mylib'. Additionally to your suggestion, I tried to change `import {Greeter} from "@mylib/index"` to `import {Greeter} from "mylib"` and to add `dependencies": { "@mylib": "file:../mylib" },` to package.json. What else is missing?

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your question. Isn't this what you wanted?
Webpack will not bundle your library, you will need to provide it separately.

Comment: You understood my question correctly :-) My problem is that adding `mylib` to externals seems to be not enough. Webpack is still bundling my library into the application bundle.

Comment: You should still be using `import {Greeter} from "@mylib"` but other than that I can't see anything wrong. It should work

Comment: TypeScript says `TS2307: Cannot find module '@mylib'.`

Comment: Forgot about the typings, updated the answer. This should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)